# How can I highlight a mat-radio-button row?

Tags: angular, angular-material

EDIT: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uhuwie

I'm having difficulty highlighting a particular row of mat-radio-button. It seems to be highlighting all the rows when the correct choice is selected. If the selected row matches the correct answer, only that row should be highlighted green, otherwise highlight red. I also need to show one question per page and move the explanation to where the question is when the answer is shown. My code is below:

```
<div *ngFor="let option of question.options">
  <div class="form-group">
    <mat-radio-group class="form-control" formControlName="answer" name="answer" (change)="radioChange($event)">
      <div [style.backgroundColor]="selectedRadioOption === question.correctAnswer ? '#00c853': 'ff0000'">
        <mat-radio-button color="primary" name="radio-group" [value]="option.optionValue" (click)="validate(answer)">
          <label>{{ option.optionText }}</label>
        </mat-radio-button>
      </div>
    </mat-radio-group>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: reproducible on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uhuwie

Comment: it is not executing. Throwing error in console

Comment: ok it should work now. please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the option is the same as the selected option also.

```
<div *ngFor="let option of question.options">
  <div class="form-group">
    <mat-radio-group class="form-control" formControlName="answer" name="answer" (change)="radioChange($event)">
      <div 
        [style.backgroundColor]=
            "selectedRadioOption === question.correctAnswer &&
             selectedRadioOption === option.optionValue
             ? '#00c853': 'ff0000'">
        <mat-radio-button color="primary" name="radio-group" [value]="option.optionValue" (click)="validate(answer)">
          <label>{{ option.optionText }}</label>
        </mat-radio-button>
      </div>
    </mat-radio-group>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Though I'm not sure why `selectedRadioOption` is a single string when you have more than one question on the page.

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't seem to highlight red if the answer is incorrect, just green on the correct answer. Yes I haven't figured out how to make it so one question is on a page.

Comment: @multiv123 I recommend separating this logic and if possible pulling it into the ts file. You can set a class for css purposes for example. One for `is-selected` and one for `is-correct`

Comment: How would I go about separating the questions onto different pages?

Comment: Happy to discuss in chat...https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199466/angular-quiz-routing